# Что Делает каждый операнд в этой строчке?

Tags: java

Что Делает каждый операнд в этой строчке?

```
double dist = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(enemyPosX - posX, 2) + Math.Pow(enemyPosY - posY, 2));
```

Comment: What does each operand in this line do?

Answer (score 5):

Если принять, что `enemyPosX` и `enemyPosY` это координаты **врага** относительно экрана, а `posX` и `posY` - координаты игрока, то

- Берем расстояние между врагом и игроком по X `(enemyPosX - posX)`
- Возводим это расстояние в квадрат `Math.pow(расстояние, 2)`
- Берем расстояние между врагом и игроком по Y `(enemyPosY - posY)`
- Возводим это расстояние в квадрат `Math.pow(расстояние, 2)`
- Складываем полученные квадраты
- Берем корень из полученной суммы
- Присваиваем результат переменной `dist`

**ИТОГО**

Ищется длина гипотенузы. Корень суммы квадратов катетов, причем длины катетов являются расстоянием между врагом и игроком

**UPDATE**

В классе `Math` есть метод `hypot` для нахождения длины гипотенузы, так что лучше не писать велосипед

```
double dist = Math.hypot(enemyPosX - posX, enemyPosY - posY);
```

[Подробнее о классе Math](http://java-help.ru/java-lang-math/)

Comment: А для чего нужно искать гипотенузу для поиска врага на экране?

Comment: @АлексейКряжев гипотенуза треугольника — это расстояние от игрока до врага.

Answer (score 1):

Рискну предположить что это расчет теоремы Пифагора:
функция Pow - это возведение в степень, сначало определяется сумма квадратов катетов а затем берется квадратный корень (функция sqrt) из этой суммы